# Why can the limit be moved inside the logarithm in $2 \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \ln \frac{\sin x}{x} \right]$?

Tags: limits, continuity

Consider the following limit:

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \ln \left( 1-(\cos x)^2 \right) - \ln x^2 \right] $$

My solution is the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \ln \left( 1-(\cos x)^2 \right) - \ln x^2 \right] &= 2 \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \ln \left( \sin x \right) - \ln x \right] = \\
&= 2 \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \ln \frac{\sin x}{x} \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

At this part, I ’moved the limit inside $\ln(\cdot)$’ to get

$$
[\dotsb]= 2 \ln \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] \right) = 2 \ln 1 = \boxed{0}
$$

*(since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$)*

**Is that ‘valid’** though? I know that this method is only correct when the function is continuous. Well, $\ln x$ is only continuous for $x>0$ and we are taking the limit at $x=0$.

Comment: How does $\sin(x) /x$ behave for negative $x$ of small absolute value? As opposed to small positive $x$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Well it gets infinitely close to $1$ both for negative and positive infinitesimal $x$ values

Comment: Then there is no problem. $\ln$ is well-defined and continuous in the neighborhood of $1$, so you are allowed to swap the order of $\lim$ and $\ln$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see where the confusion is coming from. Loosely speaking the theorem is:

$$\text{if  }\,L = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$

and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $$\lim_{x \to a} (f \ \circ \,g)(x) = f\left(L\right) = f\left(\lim_{x \to a}g(x)\right)$$

$ \\ $

So $f$ does not have to be continuous at $a$ to apply this theorem, only $L.\,(\,1$ in this case $)$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence you're applying the logarithm to (i.e., $\sin(x)/x$) converges to $1$, not $0$ (by *l'Hospital's Theorem*), thus continuity of the logarithm makes your solution valid.